# UITextField force to redraw

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

How to force a subclassed UITextField to redraw the text when the textRectForBounds gets changed?
Calling setNeedsDisplay does not work.

Comment: You tried setNeedsLayout?

Comment: Hum, interestingly enough, that does work!

Comment: Cool :) I added as an answer - feel free to accept ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `setNeedsLayout` - this should invoke when `textRectForBounds` gets changed.

Comment: This doesn't make it redraw.